# PHPstorm console input not working during debug sessions

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using a PHP script which expects user input from a command like `fgets(STDIN)`. The problem is it no longer works in the newest version of PHPStorm (10).

The same works when I run it directly (without debugger enabled) and anything I enter in the console is sent to the script (on direct run).

But during a debug session, when I try to input text at the script's prompt, it does not go to the script. My best guess is that the new REPL feature is overriding user input in console during debugging. I say this because pressing the UP/DOWN arrows opens up a popup with all PHP function names.

It used to work correctly with last version.

How can I send user input to my PHP script with this new version? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same problem right now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the same thing, but I was running into this same problem, and I was able to get it working by deselecting the "Use Console Input" checkbox in the PHPStorm Console.

Comment: This worked for me. I think that toggle is poorly named, when checked its behavior is more like "ignore standard input".

Comment: This worked for me too. For anyone interested, this button's purpose is explained here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debug-tool-window-console.html#console-toolbar

Answer (score 7):

John's answer is perfect.
I want to mention that the **Use Console Input** is a tiny icon in sidebar of the debug console. I provide you by this image

[image]

Comment: it's great that you find this helpful, thanks for comment